# DXA Model mapping issue with ReadFromXhtmlElement

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, dxa-net

I can see there is an overridable function `public override void ReadFromXhtmlElement(XmlElement xhtmlElement)` available in `MediaItem` class.

I have overrided this function in my child class. But nothing happened with this overriding. Can any one tell me from where this method is being called and why it is not functioning after overriding in inherited class?

I am using DXA 1.4 with Web 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is only called when an Entity Model is "inflated" from a Rich Text Field.

To clarify: DXA supports Media Items embedded in a Rich Text field (most obvious: embedded Images, but any kind of Media Item can be embedded). If a Rich Text field contains embedded Media Items, DXA creates Entity Models for those Media Items when processing the Rich Text field. These Media Item can initialize themselves from the data in the XHTML; the `RichTextProcessor` instantiates an appropriate `MediaItem` subclass and the calls its `ReadFromXhtmlElement` method.

See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultRichTextProcessor.cs